# Needing an explanation regarding PHP extentions

Tags: php, compilation, php-5.3

Here is a quick overview:

I just finished compiling PHP 5.3.5 and made the attempt to compile "--with" a number of different extensions. Among the extensions that I need are **mbstring** and **intl**. I can manually **phpize, configure, make, make install** the **mbstring** extension and it seems to work fine. However, I am unable to do the same for **intl**.

My *./configure* line looks like this:

```
./configure --with-openssl --with-pcre-regex --enable-calendar
            --with-curl --enable-exif --enable-ftp --with-gd
            --with-mhash --enable-mbstring --with-mysql --enable-zip
            --enable-intl --with-icu-dir=...
```

The code compiles without problem: ***./configure... make, make install***

I used the **php.ini-production** for my **php.ini** configuration and I configured Apache to use **php-cgi** for a specific domain, and that works fine as well.

A quick:

```
<?php phpinfo() ?>
```

reveals that I am in fact running the newer version of PHP. However, the extensions specified in the "**./configure...**" line do not show up anywhere on the PHP info page.

After a bit of scouting I found that I could run **phpize** on a single extension in the PHP source folder, then compile a build of the specific module and install it in my PHP extension directory. After adding:

```
extension=MY_EXT
```

in my php.ini, the extension showed up on my **phpinfo()** page.

So can anyone explain why **--with-mbstring** doesn't seem to have an effect on my compilation?

I had no compilation problems for the **intl** extension, but moving the **intl.so** file to my PHP extensions directory and adding an extension line in my php.ini has no effect.

Comment: "can anyone explain why `--with-mbstring` doesn't seem to have an effect". do you mean `--enable-intl`?

Comment: I mistyped and in fact did mean to put "--enable-EXT_NAME" (as denoted in my code block). However, putting the intl extension aside, even when I use "--enable-mbstring", that extension is not compiled/installed/enabled. It is not until I manually build it and "install" it that I get support for and see it enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/intl.installation.php), have you tried

> If your ICU is installed to a
>   non-standard directory then you might
>   want to specify its location in
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable
>   so that dynamic linker can find it: $
>   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/icu/lib
>
> Otherwise, if PHP and ICU are
>   installed to their default locations,
>   then the additional options to
>   `configure' are not needed.

Comment: I do remember seeing this block but now that I read it again I realize this is probably the issue. For some reason when I skimmed over it before I thought it was referring to the configuration associated with compiling.

Comment: I set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable and THEN compiled the intl extension. That did the trick! It doesn't answer why I am unable to build php with extensions already enabled, but at least I know one way to make it work.